# doxygen AUTOLINK_SUPPORT and sa

Tags: doxygen

Using Doxygen version 1.8.4:

When AUTOLINK_SUPPORT = NO in the configuration file, the HTML See Also section references generated by \sa (or @see) are not active links to the referenced method. When AUTOLINK_SUPPORT = YES the \sa references are active links as expected.

This seems to be a relatively recent change to doxygen behaviour: I've been using AUTOLINK_SUPPORT = NO for years to avoid having to mark all the words in the description text that would otherwise result in undesired automatic links with a '%' character, and the See Also references had remained active links.

Is there a known workaround that enables \sa references to remain active links while still having global AUTOLINK_SUPPORT disabled?

Here is a trivial test file:

```
/** The Fooy class.
*/
class Fooy
{
public:

/** foo

    The alternative is {@link bar(int, int)const the bar method}

    @param  value   A value.
    @return The value incremented.
    @see bar(int, int)const
*/
int foo (const int value) const;

/** bar

    The alternative is {@link foo(const int)const the foo method}

    @param  value   A value.
    @param  number  A number.
    @return The value plus the number.
    @see foo(const int)const
*/
int bar (int value, int number) const;
};
```

Using the auto-generated Doxyfile (doxygen -g) doxygen version 1.8.8 produces, without any warnings, the expected HTML results: The {@link bar(int, int)const the bar method} syntax results in a link named "the bar method" (and likewise for the other @link), and the @see references result in the expected links having the method signatures.

If the Doxyfile is changed so AUTOLINK_SUPPORT = NO doxygen now produces HTML in which the @see signatures are no longer links, but is otherwise the same.

If " the bar method" is removed from the first @link command doxygen outputs -

```
Fooy.hh:9: warning: unable to resolve link to `bar(int, int)' for \link command
```

And the resulting HTML has the single word "const" as the link to the html/classFooy.html file instead of the method signature and correct link. However, if the single space is removed after the comma in the argument list of the method signature the warning disappears and the link is now correct with the full signature text. Note that the space character
in the foo argument list of the second @link command must remain to have a correct signature, so removing the text " the foo method" from the command will always result in an incorrect parsing by doxygen. Restoring AUTOLINK_SUPPORT = YES does not change this behaviour. This suggests a flaw in the doxygen parser.

Back to the initial issue of getting the @see references to be links in the HTML output when AUTOLINK_SUPPORT = NO in the Doxyfile. Putting the method signatures in the @see commands inside {@link ...} wrappers fails as described above (only if the method signature has no space character does it work correctly). If the wrappers are replaced with the new @link ... @endlink syntax (and the new syntax used with the other {@link ...} commands) then the HTML output from doxygen is the expected results with full method signatures and correct links.

So the answer to this problem is that doxygen is not backwards compatible with previous in-code command syntax. Unless some workaround is known, all existing code files must be edited to accommodate the changes to the doxygen parser.

Sigh.

Comment: Did you try to use the current version of doxygen (1.8.8)?

Comment: Yes, I've tried a current binary distribution of doxygen version 1.8.8 (doxygen-1.8.8.linux.bin.tar.gz) and the same results are produced.

Comment: Note that the Doxygen file is the one internally generated by doxygen -g with only the AUTOLINK_SUPPORT option being changed.

Comment: Did you try \ref in front of the function?

Comment: Yes. I tried \ref and doxygen produced the same warnings as it did with the \link commands and the same incorrect HTML output.

Comment: Regarding the flaw in the parser part. This looks to me indeed the case. It looks to me that this problem can be overcome it by just leaving a space before the }. It looks to that the \ref works but that at the end of the line there should be a space as well. This might possibly be a regression problem., if you think this is the case please file a bugreport in bugzilla.